# Can't there be variables in range【】?or 0-1variables cannot be added or subtracted？

Tags: pycharm, gurobi

I'm writing a milp model, and one of the constraints keeps getting error. I think it's because I don't know what the rules are.

This is one of my limitations, before I add it, the model gets a good result, and after I add it, I get an error

> （ MODEL.optimize()
>         ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax）

I tried changing the range from t1 to constant and still got an error, or changing `b[]-b[]` and still got an error（）.

```
MODEL.addConstrs((gurobipy.quicksum(1-a[l, t1])for t1 in range(t, t + Changeover[l])) >= Changeover[l]*(b[l, t, q]-b[l, t, q])for q in Type for l in Line for t in range(1, 25))
```

changeover is represent changing time。`b[l,t,q]` is a binary variable representing the manufacturing status of product type q,which is equal to
1 if it is manufactured in line l at time t, and 0 otherwise.This formula means to stop the production line when it changes the product being produced

Answer (score 1):

You have parenthesis misplaced. This is a syntax error so you need to fix it first before looking into functional errors

here is the right form

```
MODEL.addConstrs(
    (
        gurobipy.quicksum(1-a[l, t1] for t1 in range(t, t + Changeover[l])) 
        >= Changeover[l]*(b[l, t, q]-b[l, t, q]) for q in Type for l in Line for t in range(1, 25)
    ), 
name='something')
```

Best